# Trying to add a colorbar to a Seaborn scatterplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, scatter-plot, colormap

I'm a geology master's student working on my dissertation with a focus on the Sulfur Dioxide output of a number of volcanoes in the South Pacific. I have a little experience with R but my supervisor recommended python (JupyterLab specifically) for generating figures and data manipulation so I'm pretty new to programming and essentially teaching myself as I go. I'm trying to use earthquake data to generate some scatterplots using seaborn but I can't seem to get a color bar to show up in the legend for the earthquake magnitude. The code I'm using is below and I'll do my best to format it in a clear way.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
from scipy import stats
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.io.img_tiles as cimgt
```

then the data sets I'm working with. These are the sets for Earthquake data.

```
df = pd.read_csv('Vanuatu Earthquakes May18-May19.csv')
df = pd.read_csv('Vanuatu Earthquakes May17-May18.csv')
df = pd.read_csv('Vanuatu Earthquakes May19-Jul20.csv')
```

and locations of the volcanoes, purely there for spatial reference.

```
dg = pd.read_csv('Volcano coordinates.csv')
```

Here's the main plot I'm trying to work with as it stands at the moment. So far I've been able to classify the earthquakes' magnitudes using the hue function but I don't like how it looks in the legend and want to convert it to a colorbar (or use a colorbar instead of hue, either/or), except I can't quite figure out how to do that. Alternatively, if there's a different function that would give me the results I'm looking for, I'm definitely open to that instead of a scatterplot. Also the black triangles are the volcanoes so those can be ignored for now.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(5.5,9))
sns.scatterplot(x='longitude', y='latitude', data=df, 
                marker='D', hue='mag', palette='colorblind', cmap='RdBu')
sns.scatterplot(x='longitude', y='latitude', data=dg, 
                marker='^', legend='brief', color='k', s=100)
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0., title='Magnitude (Mw)')
plt.xlabel('Longitude (degrees)')
plt.ylabel('Latitude (degrees)')
plt.title('Earthquake and Volcano Locations', size=15)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Hopefully that's clear enough but let me know if more info is needed!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The same method employed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49772083/10659910) regarding Seaborn barplots can be applied to a scatterplot as well. With your code that would look something like this:

```py
# ...
norm = plt.Normalize(df['mag'].min(), df['mag'].max())
sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap="RdBu", norm=norm)
sm.set_array([])

ax = sns.scatterplot(x='longitude', y='latitude', data=df, 
                     marker='D', palette='RdBu', hue='mag')
sns.scatterplot(x='longitude', y='latitude', data=dg, marker='^', 
                legend='brief', color='k', s=100, ax=ax)

# Remove the legend and add a colorbar (optional)
# ax.get_legend().remove()
# ax.figure.colorbar(sm)

# ...
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15908371) and its answers for information on manipulating the labels and ticks of the color bar.

For a complete example using the `tips` dataset:

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.set()
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
ax = sns.scatterplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", hue="size",
                     palette='RdBu', data=tips)

norm = plt.Normalize(tips['size'].min(), tips['size'].max())
sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap="RdBu", norm=norm)
sm.set_array([])

# Remove the legend and add a colorbar
ax.get_legend().remove()
ax.figure.colorbar(sm)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help! I've tried using that version of the code but I keep getting the error 
_AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get_legend'_ 
which I've searched but I'm not quite sure what needs fixing there.

Comment: @Wild.Geodude Looks like `ax` wasn't what I assumed. Try the edited code, it *should* work.

Comment: Getting closer! I got another error and changed _ax.get_legend().remove()_ to just _ax.get_legend()_ which gave me what I was looking for but all the data points are one color so now I just need to figure out how to get them to register as their respective magnitudes. Thank you!

Comment: @Wild.Geodude I apologize, there was another mistake in my code. It should work as you expect now

Comment: Thank you so much, that's exactly what I was looking for! Looks perfect now.

Comment: How would one add a label to the colorbar?

Comment: @RylanSchaeffer the `colorbar` method accepts the keyword `label` to create a label for the colorbar. See the **Notes** section of [this page](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.colorbar.html) for more details.