# How to add an axis divider in seaborn?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

The [accepted answer of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62884183/trying-to-add-a-colorbar-to-a-seaborn-scatterplot) shows how add a colorbar to a seaborn plot.

The [accepted answer of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195758/set-matplotlib-colorbar-size-to-match-graph) shows how to use an AxisDivider in matplotlib.

I'd like to *combine* both approaches and have an axis divider in seaborn. Is that possible?
For example, combining the code of the two previously mentioned posts results in an error message in seaborn:

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable


tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
ax = sns.scatterplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", hue="size", palette='RdBu', data=tips)

norm = plt.Normalize(tips['size'].min(), tips['size'].max())
sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap="RdBu", norm=norm)
sm.set_array([])

# Remove the legend and add a colorbar
ax.get_legend().remove()
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.05)
plt.colorbar(im, cax=cax)
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

Error stack trace:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-ec1c1baf2a04> in <module>
     15 divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
     16 cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.05)
---> 17 plt.colorbar(im, cax=cax)
     18 plt.show()
     19 plt.close()

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py in colorbar(mappable, cax, ax, **kw)
   2192     if ax is None:
   2193         ax = gca()
-> 2194     ret = gcf().colorbar(mappable, cax=cax, ax=ax, **kw)
   2195     return ret
   2196 colorbar.__doc__ = matplotlib.colorbar.colorbar_doc

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/figure.py in colorbar(self, mappable, cax, ax, use_gridspec, **kw)
   2341                              'panchor']
   2342         cb_kw = {k: v for k, v in kw.items() if k not in NON_COLORBAR_KEYS}
-> 2343         cb = cbar.colorbar_factory(cax, mappable, **cb_kw)
   2344 
   2345         self.sca(current_ax)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/colorbar.py in colorbar_factory(cax, mappable, **kwargs)
   1732         cb = ColorbarPatch(cax, mappable, **kwargs)
   1733     else:
-> 1734         cb = Colorbar(cax, mappable, **kwargs)
   1735 
   1736     cid = mappable.callbacksSM.connect('changed', cb.update_normal)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/colorbar.py in __init__(self, ax, mappable, **kwargs)
   1200         # Ensure the given mappable's norm has appropriate vmin and vmax set
   1201         # even if mappable.draw has not yet been called.
-> 1202         if mappable.get_array() is not None:
   1203             mappable.autoscale_None()
   1204 

AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'get_array'
```

I'd appreciate some help. :)

Comment: `im` is not defined in your code. Maybe you want `plt.colorbar(sm, ...)` instead?

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, your suggestion works fine for me. Unfortunately, I realized that when moving to `seaborn.histplot()` from `seaborn.scatterplot()`, the colormap is somehow screwed up? Could you please take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71718292/seaborn-mixing-up-colorbar-with-axis-divider