# Seaborn mixing up colorbar with axis divider?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Consider this MWE:

```py
import seaborn
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

a = np.random.randn(int(1e3))
b = np.random.rand(int(1e3))

vmin = -10
vmax = 10

seaborn.histplot(x=a, y=b, cmap='PuBu_r', cbar=True, vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)
plt.show()
plt.close()

ax = seaborn.histplot(x=a, y=b)
# Add colorbar with help of axis divier. 
norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)
sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap='PuBu_r', norm=norm)
sm.set_array([])
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
cax = divider.append_axes('right', size='5%', pad=0.05)
plt.colorbar(sm, cax=cax)
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

Naively, I'd expect both histograms to look alike, with the only difference being that the first histogram should be somewhat smaller than the second one, since the second histogram puts the colorbar with an axis divider.

However, the output is:

[image]
[image]

To be honest, I cannot explain the difference in the color scheme between the two histograms to myself. Isn't seaborn (or matplotlib) mixing things up here?

**EDIT**: As was pointed out in the comments, putting `vmin` and `vmax` explicitly into the `seaborn.histplot()` calls fixed the problem. However, when comparing the output of

```py
seaborn.histplot(x=a, y=b, cmap='PuBu_r', cbar=False, vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)
```

and

```py
ax = seaborn.histplot(x=a, y=b)
# Add colorbar with help of axis divier. 
norm = matplotlib.colors.Normalize(vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)
sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap='PuBu_r', norm=norm)
sm.set_array([])
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
cax = divider.append_axes('right', size='5%', pad=0.05)
plt.colorbar(sm, cax=cax)
```

I noticed that the second image (leaving out the colorbar) does *not* have the same size as the first image:

[image]

[image]

Is there any way to enforce this?

Comment: Your call `ax = seaborn.histplot(x=a, y=b)` doesn't set a colormap.  You'll get some default one, which seems a bit similar to the one you used for the colorbar. You'll also need to set the same `vmin` and `vmax` in both cases.

Comment: Instead of creating your own ScalarMappable, you could directly use `plt.colorbar(ax.collections[0], cax=cax)`.  (`ax.collections[0]` is where matplotlib stores the image information of the histplot).

Comment: @JohanC Thanks, putting `vmin` and `vmax` into `seaborn.histplot()` solved the problem! Unfortunately, I got another (unexpected) problem, could you please take a look at my edited question?

Comment: Also, feel free to make an answer so that I can accept it.