# How to show a grouped legend for the hue in a swarmplot

Tags: python, seaborn, legend, swarmplot

How can I group the colors shown in the picture below? If I show the legend, I see all the single value color.

```
ax1=sns.swarmplot(x='y', y='Fos', data=result, color="k", alpha=0.8, hue="y4", palette="Spectral")
plt.title('Y4');
ax1.get_legend().remove() #sns.move_legend(ax, "upper left", bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1))
    
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Since you are representing spectral/continuous values, I suggest you use a colorbar. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62886158/13525512

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new column with ranges of the continuous `hue` values.

Here is an example with seaborn's `mpg` dataset.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

mpg = sns.load_dataset('mpg')
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(16, 5))
sns.swarmplot(mpg, x='origin', y='weight', hue='mpg', palette='turbo', ax=ax1)
ax1.set_title('Default legend')

mpg['mpg range'] = pd.cut(mpg['mpg'], bins=[0, 20, 30, 40, np.inf],
                          labels=['mpg ≤ 20', '20 < mpg ≤ 30', '30 < mpg ≤ 40', 'mpg > 40'])
sns.swarmplot(mpg, x='origin', y='weight', hue='mpg range', palette='turbo', ax=ax2)
ax2.set_title('Legend with ranges')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.swarmplot legend with ranges]