# Line color as a function of column values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, colors, line-plot

I am trying to plot two columns of a pandas dataframe against each other, grouped by a values in a third column. The color of each line should be determined by that third column, i.e. one color per group.

For example:

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.1,0.2,0.3],'y':[1,2,3,2,3,4,4,3,2], 'colors':[0.3,0.3,0.3,0.7,0.7,0.7,1.3,1.3,1.3]}) 

df.groupby('colors').plot('x','y',ax=ax)
```

[image: Current output]

If I do it this way, I end up with three different lines plotting x against y, with each line a different color. I now want to determine the color by the values in 'colors'. How do I do this using a gradient colormap?

Comment: RGBA values should be within 0-1 range, what should we do about the 1.3?

Comment: Good point. Normalizing so that 0 becomes min(df['colors']) and 1.0 max(df['colors']) would be optimal.

Comment: Answer edited to account for the colorbar as well!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like seaborn is applying the color intensity automatically based on the value in hue..

```
import pandas as pd 
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [0.1,0.2,0.3,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.1,0.2,0.3],'y':[1,2,3,2,3,4,4,3,2,3,4,2], 'colors':[0.3,0.3,0.3,0.7,0.7,0.7,1.3,1.3,1.3,1.5,1.5,1.5]})

import seaborn as sns

sns.lineplot(data = df, x = 'x', y = 'y', hue = 'colors')
```

Gives:

[image: plot]

you can change the colors by adding palette argument as below:

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.lineplot(data = df, x = 'x', y = 'y', hue = 'colors', palette = 'mako')
#more combinations : viridis, mako, flare, etc.
```

gives:

[image: mako color palette]

**Edit (for colormap):**

based on answers at [Make seaborn show a colorbar instead of a legend when using hue in a bar plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49761221/make-seaborn-show-a-colorbar-instead-of-a-legend-when-using-hue-in-a-bar-plot)

```
import seaborn as sns

fig = sns.lineplot(data = df, x = 'x', y = 'y', hue = 'colors', palette = 'mako')

norm = plt.Normalize(vmin = df['colors'].min(), vmax = df['colors'].max())
sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap="mako", norm = norm)
fig.figure.colorbar(sm)
fig.get_legend().remove()
plt.show()
```

gives..

[image]

Hope that helps..

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you! Follow up: When I do this with more lines the legend still only shows four entries. Is there a way to have a colorbar instead?

Comment: look at this answer..
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49761221/make-seaborn-show-a-colorbar-instead-of-a-legend-when-using-hue-in-a-bar-plot

Comment: @nishuba I had a go at it.. edited my original answer to include colormap

Comment: That answers my question. Thanks so much! Works great now.

Answer (score 1):

Complementing to Prateek's very good answer, once you have assigned the colors based on the intensity of the palette you choose (for example `Mako`):

```
plots = sns.lineplot(data = df, x = 'x', y = 'y', hue = 'colors',palette='mako')
```

You can add a colorbar with matplotlib's function `plt.colorbar()` and assign the palette you used:

```
sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap='mako')
plt.colorbar(sm)
```

After `plt.show()`, we get the combined output:

[image]